# Not able to fetch Check Box value of GridView which is in Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am having a GridView as mentioned below

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                            Remove Lists
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I am trying to get value of Check Box on button click it always return false even when Check box is checked

Below is my Button Click Event

```
 protected void btnDeleteLists_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string str = string.Empty;

       foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvResult.Rows)
       {
           CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chk");
           if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
           {
               //Some Code                 
           }
       }       
   }
```

Page Load Event

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       cmdSearch.Text = "Search " + rbSearch.SelectedValue;
       if (SessionUtilities.Current_UserType != "3")
       {
           gvResult.Columns[gvResult.Columns.Count - 3].Visible = false;
       }
       try
       {
           if (Request.QueryString["ListType"].ToString().Trim() == "SL") ListType = 2;
           if (Request.QueryString["ListType"].ToString().Trim() == "DSL") ListType = 3;
       }
       catch { }

       if (ListType == 2) ListTypeString = "Suppression";
       if (ListType == 3) ListTypeString = "Default Suppression";
       SessionUtilities.SetTabHeadingDesc("List", ListTypeString + " List Summary", "View summary of your created lists");
       this.Title = "(View List) " + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Page_Title"].ToString();
       //if (!IsPostBack && !Is)
       //{
       BindResultGridView();

       //}

       newDt = GetAllLists();
   }
```

So where I am going wrong?

Comment: add your page load code and update panel if you have

Comment: instead of `//if (!IsPostBack && !Is) //{ BindResultGridView(); //}` just use `if (!IsPostBack) { BindResultGridView(); }` and you are done. don't bind the gridview again in the pageload if your state is in the `postback`.

Comment: You are right thanxxx... I did not even noticed that Thanx its working now

Comment: Welcome, I will post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
`//if (!IsPostBack && !Is) //{ BindResultGridView(); //}`
 just use `if
 (!IsPostBack) { BindResultGridView(); }` and you are done.

Explanation:-
If you bind the gridview again in the page load when your page is in the postback stage it will lose the changes you done last time. it will **reinitialize** the whole gridview and hence your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use either the prerender event or the rowdatabound event of the gridview to get the checkbox value in update panel